# Online source with classical music concerts to come

Tags: classical-music

I am sorry  in case it happens to be  a severe off-topic, but with my interest in classical music recently revived I was looking for specific performances all over the world, as in Amsterdam (where I live) it is not often to have a good concert, so I'd consider travelling to attend it.

For example, I have found [bachtrack](https://bachtrack.com/) to be quite useful: I can just type "Tchaikovsky Symphony 6" there and get a list of upcoming concerts. At the same time, I am not sure whether this list is comprehensive - a lot of famous pieces (like an aforementioned symphony) are only played a dozen times a year worldwide according to bachtrack, which I find hard to believe. Are there better sources?

Comment: A lot of CD labels provide a newsletter, which among others lists the scheduled concerts of their exclusive artists (which obviously may increase sales of the respective recordings), but I'm not aware of a more global portal.

Answer (score 1):

The International Gustav Mahler society [used to have](https://www.gustav-mahler.org/mahler/concerts-f-e.cfm) a Mahler-specific calendar, but unfortunately it is now defunct.

[Universal Edition](http://www.universaledition.com/performances-and-calendar) also has a tool that you can use, though I've never used it before, so I can't speak to its quality.

Answer (score 1):

For concerts in the UK [Concert Diary](http://www.concert-diary.com/) is a good source - I have listed concerts there and gone to concerts listed.  Some posts on Tripadvisor suggested, for France ["Offi"](http://www.offi.fr/concerts/classique.html), and for Germany ["Classictic"](https://www.classictic.com/en/)